# what type of graph should l use (python mtaplotlib) (bar plot with binned domain)

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

day = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  # time from 0 to 5 am

average_bpm = [78, 92, 68, 99]

plt.hist(average_bpm, day, label='p1', histtype='bar')

plt.xlabel('BPM')
plt.ylabel('TIME OF DAY')
plt.title('avb 1')
plt.legend()


plt.show()
```

l want the graph to show avg heart bpm for each hour of the day, l want the bars to be at x in between the 0 1 2.. 5 numbers and their heights to be as high as the avg bpm for that hour
with plt.bar l'm going to have to type 1-2 2-3... (and it won't look as good) but with hists l could just enter the variable day
but with hists the hights are messed up

so both hists and bars didn't workout for me. is there any mode l could use with them/any other graph type to get the desired graph??

**so basically what l want is a bar plot with binned range..**

Comment: so what l want is a bar plot with binned range..

Comment: can you add sample graph for 3-4 values

Comment: @GirishDattatrayHegde done

Comment: @GirishDattatrayHegde would a plot like this be acceptable (it's a line graph but plotted via stairs so it looks like a bar graph) [here](https://imgur.com/a/cDJC6Wh)